# How do you express "Every pair of integer has a greatest common divisor" in mathematical terms?

Tags: propositional-calculus, gcd-and-lcm, logic-translation

> How do you express "All pairs of integer have a greatest common divisor" in mathematical term?

[image: My answer]

This is what I came up with but I'm unsure if it's right.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Don't you want to say $\forall x, \forall y, \exists g$ such that $\forall a \in \mathbb Z,  (a|x\land a|y)\implies a|g$?

Comment: No, that just says there are common divisors $a, b$ such that $a \ge b$.  For example, it would be true for $a=b=1$.

Comment: You'll want to say $\forall b\in \Bbb{Z}$, since $a$ should be greater than *any* other divisor, not just *some* divisor.

Comment: That’s not enough, though, you also need that $g$ is a common divisor. @J.W.Tanner

Comment: @R.Burton Thanks, I think that's it!

Comment: Does your language include $0?$ You have to be careful about “greatest common divisor” in that case - all integers are divisors of $0,$ but the GCD of $0$ and $0$ is $0.$

Comment: @R.Burton Actually on second thought, wouldn't changing it to $\forall b$, make the premise always false? Not sure if that would still make sense

Comment: Sorry, you also need to change the last conjunction $\land(a\ge b)$ to an implication $\implies (a\ge b)$. That is, *if* $a$ and $b$ are common divisors then $a\ge b$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You're right, that just makes it more complicated, maybe I don't have to care about 0 for this question

Comment: You could also use $(b>a)\implies \neg(b\mid x\land b\mid y)$

Comment: @R.Burton Yes I did that as well, would that take care of the previous problem I said? So the statement would always be true if b doesn't divide x and y... Which seems to not be a problem hmm!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean that $x$ and $y$ are only divisible by a single number, then you are just describing powers of primes.

Comment: Good point, @ThomasAndrews

Comment: @R.Burton Do you think I should also add that a does not equal b, and change the conclusion to $a > b$ instead of $a >= b$? Since both a and b could be, say 2, but the greatest common divisor of 6 and 12 is not 2.

Comment: It is not necessary to do so, but you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct statement is:

$$\forall x,y\left(\exists d\left(d\mid x\land d\mid y\land\forall e\left((e\mid x\land e\mid y)\Rightarrow e\leq d\right)\right)\right)
$$

This is only true if your language is the positive integers.

If the language includes zero you need something like:

$$\forall x,y\left((x=0\land y=0)\lor\\\exists d\left(d\mid x\land d\mid y\land\forall e\left((e\mid x\land e\mid y)\Rightarrow e\leq d\right)\right)\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks, I just have one question: what if e = d? Wouldn't that make it not mandatory to be the "greatest" common divisor?

Comment: If that was the only $e,$ but we said “for all $e$.” So if $x=4,y=6$ and $d=e=1,$ all the statements would be true, but when $d=1,e=2,$ the statement is false. So $d=1$ does not satisfy our condition for this expression.